# Print from specific elements in python tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Am trying to print elements of `index 1` like `4994 2993 100 20.5` from my tuple but it print `('dan', '2993')`.

```
b = (("ben","4994"),("dan","2993"),("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))


print(b[1])
```

Have searched on this site and none of the answer provided gives me clue to solve this.

Comment: Your code behaves correctly - it is printing the first element of your tuple as you say.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking in a list comprehension:

```
b = (("ben","4994"),("dan","2993"),("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))
new_b = [i for _, i in b]
```

Output:

```
['4994', '2993', 100, 20.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another list comprehension way:

```
b = (("ben","4994"),("dan","2993"),("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))
new_b = [i[1] for i in b]
# ['4994', '2993', 100, 20.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = (("ben","4994"),("dan","2993"),("Hans",100),("Frank",20.5))

for item in b:
    print(item[1])
```

In this case you are trying to access the second element of a two-items tuple. Using slicing would be:

```
>>> b[0][1]
```

and you will get as output>

```
>>> '4994'
```

If you put this tuple into a for loop, the first element (item in my code) would be: ("ben","4994") and when you print(item[1]) you are having access to the second level of slicing, that is: '4994' in the first running of the loop and so on.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.